# Are there vunerabilities with this authentication mechanism?

Tags: encryption, authentication, passwords, hash, protocols

I am trying to come up with a way to implement token-based authentication for a REST API without the need for SSL. The goal here is to avoid sending any *sensitive* information across the wire.

I was thinking of the following approach:

**Step 1** - Client asks for request token from server and supplies a username.

**Step 2** - Server returns user password salt & request timestamp.

**Step 3** - Client then calculates password hash based on salt + actual password (captured via input)

**Step 4** - Client then generates token by hashing password hash + request timestamp.

**Step 5** - Client sends token & username & request timestamp to server

**Step 6** - Server verifies authentication by re-generating same token with details provided.

From what I can tell nothing that isn't public already is going over the wire so packet sniffers would be out of luck. The token is hashed using the original password (essentially the secret key) so MitM are covered. Finally, the original timestamp from the initial request is sent back (and is part of the hash) therefore Replay attacks should be out of the question.

I have only started looking at security therefore pretty much a novice at this stuff so any help/advice would be appreciated!

**Update**

I should have been more clear with regards to the SSL.... it's not that I am trying my best to avoid using SSL, it's more catering for the scenario where it isn't an option. Also, please target your answers more to the reasons *why* this approach wouldn't work & if it could be tweaked to work rather than "use SSL".

Comment: Discloses user's user name.

Comment: @chao-mu Username is already publicly available, consider a twitter type system.

Comment: But not necessarily publicly associated with the origin of the request. This would allow an attacker to focus their attack.

Comment: As is the usual: Don't try and roll your own xx just to bypass SSL. Why can't you use SSL?

Comment: @James "_Username is already publicly available, consider a twitter type system._" knowing the list of registered user names is not the same thing as knowing the user name used in every requests

Comment: @SteveS "_Don't try and roll your own xx just to bypass SSL._" ...unless **you know you can come up with something strictly better than SSL/TLS (for every possible criteria), because you know some much more than all the designers of SSL**, of course. ;)

Comment: APOP is an authentication mechanism very similar to what you propose.

Comment: @SteveS I am not just trying to roll my own to bypass SSL, I am trying to roll my own incase SSL isn't an option. Ideally I would like to have an approach which is going to work with or without SSL, albeit SSL would always be more secure.

Comment: Even at that, I haven't just blindly came up with this approach. I have researched a few different authentication prototcols and seen one that was similar to this but used API Keys (essentially the public key) as part of it. This is pretty much the same thing but excluding the API key.

Comment: @James "_SSL would always be more secure._" **only** TLS (or equivalent) is going to be secure, unless you are willing to re-define "secure". Otherwise, please rate the security properties you want in order of priority.

Comment: It should be a FAQ that "_I want to do X, but I don't want to use the tool Y, despite the fact that it this tool is a widely used, standard tool which implements X and has been properly reviewed._" is the way **to not** ask a security question, a CS question, or an engineering question in general.

Comment: @curiousguy I take your point, however, this is a learning curve for me and if I can be clear on the reasons *why* I shouldn't be doing something rather *you should be using X* then I will have a better understanding of how it all works. I take everyones point with regards to using SSL, however, not everyone can use SSL. Not only that but confidentiality may not be a high priority therefore SSL maybe unnecessary.

Comment: -1 for trying to avoid TLS/SSL.  You are doing it wrong,  hopefully thse ideas don't spread.

Comment: @Rook your comment is a little ignorant. Not all systems require SSL and from what I am reading there are definitely ways of implementing ones which are still secure (to a reasonable extent). There are big companies who don't use SSL and still provide a secure authentication protocol, Amazon being one (and I think Microsoft Azure as well).

Comment: @James "_Not only that but confidentiality may not be a high priority therefore SSL maybe unnecessary._" TLS does not only protects confidentiality, but also **session integrity**. OTOH, if you don't care about security...

Comment: @curiousguy So essentially what your saying is if your not using TLS/SSL your basically setting yourself up for a bad fall? Amazon obviously push the use of TLS/SSL however they still offer non-HTTPS solutions i.e. http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1928#HTTP. So does it not prove that there are some scenarios where SSL isn't a necessity?

Comment: @James "_still secure (to a reasonable extent)._" please define "reasonable" security. Please explain the security properties you need and those you might leave out.

Comment: @James "_So does it not prove that there are some scenarios where SSL isn't a necessity?_" SSL is not a necessity, but whenever session integrity and privacy is needed, it comes handy. In other cases, you might want message integrity, and use other tools.

Comment: @James "_Amazon obviously push the use of TLS/SSL however they still offer non-HTTPS solutions i.e. aws.amazon.com/articles/1928#HTTP._" The section on **Replay Attacks** is interesting: "The best mechanism for defense against a replay attack is to ensure all your requests are made over an SSL connection." (...) "If you do not use the Expires parameter, and rely only on the timestamp parameter, your requests are subject to a request expiration period, which varies by service, but can be as long as 15 minutes." Amazon makes very clear that the same security are not provided without SSL as with.

Comment: (...) There is no law which says that you must use TLS in all circumstances. That would be crazy. There are other valid security tools. In many contexts, TLS is not even applicable (code signing, message signing, non-repudiation...). In some cases, the relevant security properties do not depend on session level privacy or integrity (notably when downloading a public, signed message).

Comment: (...) In the context of an interactive protocol where the user is identified, authenticated, and can remotely execute a command with its user rights, it is hard to believe that session secrecy and integrity are not desirable security properties.

Comment: @curiousguy I think the issue was I deviated frOm my original question. I asked for advice on whether the above protocol was safe. I understand that it's not as it discloses too much information. The discussion then turned to *just because TLS is the recommended approach doesn't mean it's the only one*. However, in hindsight I can see why you would be silly not to use it considering it does essentially cover all vurnerabilities with the proposed approach. Also, it means you can use simple authentication e.g. Basic, and be pretty confident that it's secure..

Comment: I would probably still go with perhaps a token based approach in cohesion with TLS and only use Basic authentication for the initial request. Avoids having to send the username/password across the wire for *every* request and also means I wouldn't need to store it as plain-text at the client side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am trying to come up with a way to implement token-based authentication for a REST API without the need for SSL.

Don't!

**Use SSL (well, TLS actually).**

> nothing that isn't public already is going over the wire

This is obviously not exact:

- the user name is captured; TLS would hide user name (I am not saying it is a serious still, but it is an information which is disclosed);
- a hash based on available information is captured and passwords can now be tried (dictionary attack).

> I have only started looking at security therefore pretty much a novice at this stuff so any help/advice would be appreciated!

**Use the proper tools. Don't try make your own protocols.** If you try to come up with your own security protocols, they will almost always be flawed.

There are many issues with your protocol:

- discloses user name (might not be huge issue, but still)
- discloses password hash: **allows off-line attack on password**
- the server needs to know all **passwords in clear-text** (either by storing them in clear-text, or storing them encrypted with symmetric encryption, and storing the encryption key) (well not the user password, but the real user secret authenticator)
- and the worst part: **absolutely no protection against an active attacker**

### Replying to your update:

> I should have been more clear with regards to the SSL.... it's not that I am trying my best to avoid using SSL, it's more catering for the scenario where it isn't an option.

**Why** isn't it an option in this scenario?

> Also, please target your answers more to the reasons why this approach wouldn't work & if it could be tweaked to work rather than "use SSL".

**TLS gives you transport level "security": secrecy and integrity** (actually, secrecy is limited, as the size of message is leaked; the secrecy of fixed-size keys is protected).

It can be "tweaked" to work without actually using TLS, *if you reimplement most of TLS* to get transport security without TLS. The implementation cost would be great, and even if you can get all the details right, your implementation might not perform as well as a carefully optimised TLS implementation.

The important question is **why you would not want to use TLS**.

Comment: Ok I can see where this sort of approach is vurnerable. Would you say using Basic authentication with SSL is pretty secure?

Comment: @James If the TLS certificate of the server is properly checked, then yes, I would say it's secure. Be careful about your root **certificates store**: only keep necessary root certificates. One _rogue CA_ is enough to compromise TLS server authentication.

Comment: From what I have been reading though TLS isn't always enough you should still provide some form of protection on the actual data being transmitted e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2005/04/25/end-to-end-security-or-why-you-shouldn-t-drive-your-motorcycle-naked.aspx

Comment: Like I said it's not like I want to not use TLS, I am not the guy who makes the decisions therefore if I come up against "we can't afford a TLS" then I was hoping there could be another alternative. From the answers I have been given (not particular to my protocol suggestion) it appears the answer is *no*. Are you able to generate your own TLS certificate if it's used purely for encryption & not for authentication?

Comment: @James "_if I come up against "we can't afford a TLS"_" then answer: how do you know? have you tried? If TLS is too costly, maybe it's just a bad configuration. F.ex. there is no point wasting cycles with a 4000 bits RSA key, as this won't be the weakest point of the whole system anyway. If you have questions about the performance of TLS, there are experts on this forum.

Comment: (...) "_Are you able to generate your own TLS certificate if it's used purely for encryption & not for authentication?_" Your question doesn't make sense. **A certificate is for authentication.** If you think there is no need for authentication (and you are certainly wrong here), you can use the **anonymous** key establishment protocol of TLS (anon DH). But again, **I am pretty sure that you really want authentication**.

Comment: Pretty sure I read somewhere that a certificate used for authentication shouldn't also be used for encryption. Will try find the resource  (I could be possibly referring to digital signatures?). Also with regards to the "*We can't afford TLS*" I was referring to actual money cost, not performance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4005/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-james)

Answer (score 6):

You disclose enough information to allow offline brute-forcing of the password.

Let's review. The eavesdropper knows the timestamp, salt, and result of hash(hash(password + salt) + timestamp). The attacker can run hash(hash(*guess* + salt) + timestamp) repeatedly with different values of "guess" until the result equals the observed token. The password is then known.

Comment: Yeah I see where your coming from now, if the username wasn't part of the request would it make it any less vurnerable?

Comment: The password could still be brute forced, since I am describing an offline attack.

Comment: The example I took this from is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386930/rest-api-authorization-authentication-web-mobile. I was thinking I could possibly get away without using the who API key end of things (as I am not publically opening the API up to developers). Is it possible to implement a token-based system which is secure without having to implement something like oAuth....that article seems to suggest it's doable?

Comment: I think further discussion may be better had in its own thread. "Doable" can mean a lot of things. You certainly will not be saving time/effort/tears trying to write it yourself.

Comment: @James "_if the username wasn't part of the request would it make it any less vurnerable?_" How would the server check the password, not knowing the username?

Comment: @curiousguy I understand if the username isn't sent then the server wouldn't be able to verify it (in the context of the proposed protocol). I would obviously need to implement some form of "request" token which would be mapped to a particular user for X amount of time. Just asking out of curiosity if the username wasn't there, would it make the protocol any less/more secure.

Comment: @James removing the username would be like taking a cup full of water out of the ocean. Even if somehow the username could be removed, the attacker probably can figure it out through other means (as you said it was publicly available). Your question has been fully answered with plenty of examples: there are vulnerabilities in your authentication mechanism.

Comment: @James "_I would obviously need to implement some form of "request" token which would be mapped to a particular user for X amount of time._" You remove the username from the exchange, but you need to introduce some "pseudonym" (or temporary ID if you prefer) to replace it. So, you would have to define another protocol to map this temporary ID to a  username. The *security properties of the whole system* would presumably be very similar. But with a more complicated (state-full) protocol, potentially more difficult to analyse, with more occasion to miss a security issue, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is horribly wrong. As curious guy said, never never never try to make your own authentication protocols. What is more disturbing is that you confidently say it avoids replay attacks, when it doesn't at all.

If someone with a sniffer captures Step 5, he will always manage to login, because **the client is sending back the timestamp** and the server **trusts** it. So you can reuse that timestamp forever, until the password is changed. Even if you add a time window, the attacker only needs to automate it to login as soon as the client sends his response.

Comment: I don't recall ever *confidently* saying it avoids replay attacks, I said *should be out of the question* based on my understanding. I thought by hashing the timestamp as part of the token and sending it back across the server could then check if the request token for that user has already been A) authorised or B) expired.

Comment: @James "_check if the request token for that user has already been A) authorised or B) expired._" So, you need to **explicitly** mention the expiration check in the protocol, and you need to describe precisely the way the check is run. In a security protocol, all the details matter.

Comment: @curiousguy I will update the my question to accomodate that, I should have explictly stated that's what the purpose of the timestamp.

Comment: Checking if request token was authorized doesn't help, because attacker could after observing step 2 disrupt communication with the client (e.g. by some kind of network attack slowing down client's network) and issue his own response with the timestamp first. If you allow only one response with this timestamp, you then allow very easy DOS attack on the protocol - I can prevent any client from logging in as long as I can send response faster than they do. If you allow many responses with the same timestamp, I can bruteforce it.

Comment: @StasM "_you then allow very easy DOS attack on the protocol - I can prevent any client from logging in as long as I can send response faster than they do._" which protocol does not have this property?

Comment: @curiousguy I think many protocols that ignore invalid data and do not cancel communication when getting some invalid data would not be susceptible o this particular problem.

Comment: @StasM Yes, protocols with per-packet integrity feature can avoid this attack (so anything based on regular TCP is out of luck (and TCP with the MD5 integrity option is not "regular" TCP)). F.ex. IPsec-AH. Oh, wait, if you have IPsec, why not also enable ESP? Then the adversary could not even read any application level data (and you can use TCP - people use TCP for everything now). It is another "do not reinvent the wheel" case.

Comment: It's OK to make your own authentication protocol if that's what you're good at, but you shouldn't use it in production until after you've published an article about it in a reputable cryptography research journal and it's been recommended by other information security experts.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of big problems here.

If you're talking about a browser as the client, then you've got a major vulnerability straight away. Unless you're implementing the code as a greasemonkey script (i.e. already at the client) then the code to implement step 3 has to be sent over the unencrypted channel (presenting an opportunity for it to be intercepted and modified).

Leaving this aside, your proposal will authenticate the username - but how do you then maintain a session / authenticate further requests from the client?

Even without knowing the username and password, nor changing the data stream, an eavesdropper could assume the indentity (depending on how session management is implemented) by sniffing and replaying the token provided by the client.

Yes, it's a bit better than sending a password in clear text - but only just. And yes, there is a benefit in preventing the diclosure of a password even where there is no requirement to add strong security to the actual transactions being processed (but your approach can be subverted by MITM to reveal the actual password).

Comment: If the salt is intercepted & modified at step 2, surely this would simply mean that when the token comes back to the server the hash values won't match and the server would reject (as the salt has changed). Also, I don't see how the original password could be revealed (unless you are referring to brute-force attack). If the salt is high-entropy e.g. 16+ bytes, surely this would practically nullify the chances of it being cracked in any reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @James "_If the salt is intercepted & modified at step 2,_" who said the salt would be modified? "_If the salt is high-entropy e.g. 16+ bytes, surely this would practically nullify the chances of it being cracked in any reasonable amount of time?_" entropy? what are you talking about? **The salt is sent in clear.** It is constant for a given user, and known by the attacker (who can listen to packets on the wire, by hypothesis). **The entropy of the salt is zero.**

Comment: @curiousguy yeah that was a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: "_If you're talking about a browser as the client_" The question was not explicit about the context (generic client/browser vs. specialized client), but James latter explained he was talking about a mobile app, so this particular concern does not apply in his case. But still, it is an important remark.

Comment: @James: if the client is a browser, then the code used to generate the hash is sent as cleartext javascript and can hence be modified